# CSS cleaner to "unfold" style sheets?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a web service or (OS X) software that will take a style sheet like this one:

```
h1,h2 {margin-bottom:1em;}
h2.special {color:red;text-align:justify;}
p {margin-bottom:1em;font-weight:bold; }
```

and transform it into this:

```
h1,h2,p {margin-bottom:1em;}
h2.special {color:red}
h2.special {text-align:justify;}
p {font-weight:bold;}
```

I.e., I need something that will take *each unique attribute / value combination* in a CSS file and then group all selectors that use it.

It seems to me that this is a trivial problem, but the only bit of “coding” I’m capable of is a bit of RegEx - seems that doesn’t give me a solution here.

Thank you.

*Note:*

I'm aware that this approach may not lead to (size) optimization. It's not for a live site/CSS, but to analyze and "weed out" unnecessarily complex style sheets. After that step, attributes will be grouped again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://www.cssoptimiser.com/optimize.php
Although I'm not sure how converting `h2.special {color:red;text-align:justify;}` to

```
h2.special {color:red}
h2.special {text-align:justify;}
```

would be an improvement.
But that optimizer did do the other part (margin-bottom).

Basically just google "CSS optimizer"

Comment: Better than the other CSS optimizers I've seen. It still does not separate by declaration, but I can do that with some RegEx. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at a CSS extension framework such as: http://lesscss.org/

It does not clean your CSS, but allows you to create cleaner CSS.

Comment: Less is great to create clean CSS, but right now I need to analyze + fix legacy CSS. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at Compass http://compass-style.org/.
It's an ruby based CSS framework

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can suggest a solution to your actual question (I've given the question +1 because it's a good question, well asked, and without an obvious answer), but with regard to "weeding out" unnecessary styles, you could try the [Dust Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) Firefox plugin.